# Apply normalize.css only to a component on a page?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use a css wizard type [component](http://codepen.io/tiagorigoletto/pen/HCtDE) i found:

```
.wizard li {
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 40px;
  margin-right: -7px;
  width: auto;
}

.wizard li::before, .wizard li::after {
  border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
  border-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.wizard li::before {
    border-width: 25px; 
  margin-top: -16px;
  margin-left: 84px;
}


.wizard li::after {
    border-left-color: #E4E4E4;
  border-width: 21px; 
  margin-top: -12px;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.wizard li.selected {
  background-color: #FF4F65;
  color: #fff;
}

.wizard li.selected::after {
  border-left-color: #FF4F65;
}

.wizard li:last-child::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

I want to use this on a large site that does not use a normalize/reset. The component only seems to work when you use normalize.css. Is there any way that i can just use normalize.css on this component rather than an entire page?

Comment: May I recommend you just pick put the `li` part from the reset instead

Comment: Yes, just paste relevant parts adding .wizard but hmmmmmmmm what about normalizing all site??? If layout does not change then it doesn't hurt. If it changes then your site is already broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the element, you'll see that the `font-family` is causing the issue.

[From normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css):

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif; /* i'm causing it */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

So simply add some `font-family` to the `.wizard li`, like `arial`.

[Check the codepen](http://codepen.io/vucko/pen/ZWaYmy)

Or if you're using some custom font, then you have to modify the values (`border-width`, `margin-top`, `margin-left`) for the pseudo elements (`.wizard li::before` and `.wizard li::after`).